# Topological issues in large deviation principle

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, large-deviation-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space, let $B_X$ be its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and let $B$ be the completion of $B_X$ under some regular measure $\mu $. We say that the family of probability measures $\mu_\epsilon$, defined on $(X,B)$ and absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu $, satisfies the large deviation principle with the rate function $I$ if

$$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon \log \left ( \mu_\epsilon(F) \right ) \leq -\inf_{x \in F} I(x) \\
\liminf_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon \log \left ( \mu_\epsilon(G) \right ) \geq -\inf_{x \in G} I(x)$$

whenever $F$ is closed and $G$ is open. (One can generalize somewhat, but I don't think it is necessary for this context.) I have seen examples that show that some "natural" situations where, if we allowed $F,G$ to be arbitrary measurable sets, we would not have an LDP, yet we "should" have one.

For instance, if $\mu_\epsilon$ is the uniform distribution on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, then the large deviation principle should tell us that $\mu_\epsilon$ "collapses to $0$", and the rate function should be $0$ at $0$ and $+\infty$ elsewhere. But if we drop the openness requirement in the lower bound, then we can take $G=\{ 0 \}$, in which case the inequality reads $-\infty \geq 0$, which is not true.

I imagine there is a similar example if we drop the closedness requirement in the upper bound. So I understand logically that these topological constraints are necessary. But these counterexamples don't give me an intuition for why the topological constraints should be the way they are.

With that in mind: why, intuitively, should the large deviation lower bound hold for open sets, and the upper bound for closed sets? For instance, is this a manifestation of the idea that open sets are "large" while closed sets are "small"?

Comment: The idea is to ask that for every $A$ in $B$, $$-\inf_{x \in \mathrm{Int}(A)} I(x)\leqslant\liminf_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon \log \mu_\epsilon(A) \leqslant\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon \log \mu_\epsilon(A) \leqslant -\inf_{x \in \mathrm{Cl}(A)} I(x),$$ where $\mathrm{Int}(A)$ denotes the interior of $A$ and $\mathrm{Cl}(A)$ the closure of $A$. The two assertions in your post are the special cases of this when $A$ is open (equivalent to $A=\mathrm{Int}(A)$) and when $A$ is closed (equivalent to $A=\mathrm{Cl}(A)$).

Comment: As you know, one would like to write $\mu_\epsilon(A)=\exp(-I(A)/\epsilon+o(1/\epsilon))$ for some $I(A)$ but this is often not possible for every $A$ hence one falls back on the limsup/liminf and interior/closure formulation in my first comment. Finally the idea behind this is simply that $\mathrm{Int}(A)\subseteq A\subseteq\mathrm{Cl}(A).$

Comment: @Did OK, let's look at that formulation (the more general one). Suppose we have a situation where $\inf_{x \in \text{Cl}(A)} I(x) < \inf_{x \in \text{Int}(A)} I(x)$ (so that the infimum is approached and/or attained on the boundary). One case is with $\mu_\epsilon$ is as in my example and $A=\{ 0 \}$. Can we say anything in particular about $\mu_\epsilon$ in this situation? Is $\mu_\epsilon$ necessarily "concentrating on $\partial A$" in some sense?

Comment: Only that it is bounded by these two exponentials with different exponents (this is the massive improvement the founders of large deviations theory brought to the field when they realized nothing more could be said, that is, that open and closed sets were the bounding posts of the general case).

Comment: @Ian Note that the situation is exactly the same for weak convergence of measures; Portmanteau's theorem states that $\mu_n \to \mu$ (weakly) iff $$\mu(A) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mu_n(A)$$ for any open set $A$ or $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mu_n(A) \leq \mu(A)$$ for any closed set $A$.

Comment: @saz Good point. On that subject, I seem to frequently see "a weak convergence approach to ..." in my reading. Do you have any suggestion for a reference on this sort of thing?

Comment: @saz I'm now thinking a little bit from that point of view. It makes sense that $\delta_{1/n}$ only converges weakly to $\delta_0$, because I can give $\mathbb{R}$ the discrete topology instead of its usual topology, and then $1/n$ is not "close" to $0$ in any sense. So if $U_A$ is the uniform measure probability measure supported on $A$, does $U_{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}$ only converge weakly to $\delta_0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$? If so, why? (To me this seems "less topological" than the previous example, since $\{ 0 \}=\bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is a purely set-theoretic fact.)

Comment: @Ian Yes, $U_{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}$ converges weakly to $\delta_0$; that's not difficult to show using the definition of weak convergence. And no, unfortunately I don't have a good reference for this weak-convergence-approach-stuff (but yeah, it is in fact used quite frequently).

Comment: @saz It was clear to me that it converges weakly; I was asking whether it doesn't also converge in any stronger sense. But I see now that it actually doesn't even converge setwise, which seems to explain the issue. That's interesting, because somehow this really does seem like "stronger" convergence than the $\delta_{1/n}$ situation.